# Local variable in FOR DO Statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

does the variable 'var' gets destroyed before displaying its value?

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%G IN ('dir') DO (
set var=%%G
echo %var%
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will never work since the reference to `%var%` is resolved when the body of the loop is parsed.  You have to enable delayed variable expansion and use `!var!` instead:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G IN ('dir') DO (
    SET VAR=%%G
    ECHO !VAR!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

You can read all about it by type `SET /?` at a command line ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need delayed expansion:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%G IN ('dir') DO (
    set var=%%G
    echo !var!
)
endlocal
```

The reason it doesn't appear to be working is because `%var%` is evaluated at the time the entire command is parsed. The command is the *entire* four lines of the `for` statement. By using delayed expansion, you defer the evaluation of `!var!` to when the actual `echo` is executed, when it's been set correctly.