# How Can I lock a variable in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd, passwords

The short and skinny is that I am trying to create a script for a self serve password reset script that can be delivered via our remote application program (in this case, 2X).

The current iteration of my script is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET passchange=%username%
ECHO Changing password for %passchange%
runas /profile /user:administrator "net user %passchange% * /domain"

PAUSE
```

I arrived at the current iteration because net user on its own returned "System Error 5 has occurred.  Access Denied."  As a result I am attempting to elevate the command using runas.

That elevation is also why I'm attempting to map a custom variable to a system variable, as when using runas, %username% maps to administrator instead of the logged in user.  So what I'd like to do is find some way to lock that %passchange% variable.

Or maybe there's a better way to accomplish this so that it can be run as the user without the runas method of elevation?  We do not plan to give users admin rights.  Unless this is another permission issue?

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  Variables in batch scripts are evaluated before the line is executed, so `%passchange%` will be evaluated in the context of the batch script, not in the context of the `runas` process.  (I'm not sure how you're going to get the admin password in there, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local variable in FOR DO Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084846/local-variable-in-for-do-statement)

Comment: Thanks Harry.  I kind of feel like a fool, what I thought was it prompting to change the admin password was it prompting for the password for elevation.  I don't think it would have clicked in my head without your comment.  Aside from that little snag, it appears to work as necessary.  I'm going to be looking at other, better avenues for privilege escalation.